# Retrieve date wise data from database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my database I have 1 table with `date` as one of the column, which stores the date when user add some data in my table.

Now I want to retrieve the data for the current month alone. I searched through Google but didn't get appropriate answer.

My table creation code:

```
"create table incomexpense(
    _id integer primary key autoincrement,
    "+"price text not null,description text not null,
    "+"quantity text not null,
    "+"total text not null,
    "+"category text not null,
    "+"recurrence text not null,
    "+"date text not null,
    "+"groups text not null,
    "+" recurrenceid text not null);";
```

Can anyone please help how to get the date of 7th day form the current date.

Comment: share database table structure.

Comment: What format is the the date in?  Without knowing that, it's almost impossible to give any recommendations.

Comment: Barak..date format is "dd/MM/yyyy"..Also i got 1 answer:             select column_name from table_name where strftime('%Y-%m', column_name) = '2011-05';In this they r giving static value for date'2011-05'.But i want is it should load automatically the current year and month..

Answer (score 7):

If you want to "automatically" load the current year/month, use SQLite's `strftime` function with `'now'` modifier & `'%Y-%m'` format mask.

```
select strftime('%Y-%m', 'now');
```

Now, coming to your question:

> Now I want to retrieve the data for the current month alone.

Well, here comes a mess. You [can't store the date as a datetime type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), instead it's stored as a string in a format SQLite can't parse using date functions. So you'll have to convert it into a format which [SQLite can understand](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

You can do that by using the usual `substr` function

```
substr(exp_date, 7) || '-' || substr(exp_date, 4,2) || '-' || substr(exp_date, 1,2)
```

So this will covert `dd/mm/yyyy` to `YYYY-mm-dd` format.

So the full query will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   incomexpense
WHERE  Strftime('%Y-%m', 'now') = Strftime('%Y-%m', Substr(exp_date, 7)
                                                    || '-'
                                                    || Substr(exp_date, 4, 2)
                                                    || '-'
                                                    || Substr(exp_date, 1, 2))
```

See how this works [over here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c13a4/1).

Comment: Thanks Sathya..Can anyone please tell me..how can i get the date of 7days from the current date..

Comment: @prakash.k -> `select date('now','+7 days')`

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have a bulit in data type as "Date". You can either store it as string and parse it appropriately when you use it. 
So with this option, unless you retrive and parse the Date , you won't be able to find the records in current month.

Other option is you store it as number - Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

With some calculation in the where clause you can find out the records for the current month.