# Retrive date wise data from SQLITE database kotlin

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

I have one SQlite database where i store some data with date.

Now i want to get data date wise like:

1. Month wise - it means i pass the value like Current date is EndDate to this month 1st date.
2. Year wise - it means i want to get data 1st-april-20..previews to 31-march-20..current
3. Start and End date wise - hear is which i pass date.

For that i got one solution is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630215/retrieve-date-wise-data-from-database-in-android) for java.

But i have no idea this HOW TO WORK. Anyone please explain me how to work this and How to i get data as i mention above. FOR KOTLIN

**`TABLE`**

```
db.createTable(customerDetail, true,
                credit_id to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT,
                credit_type to TEXT,
                c_id to TEXT,
                credit_amount to TEXT,
                credit_date to TEXT,
                addFrom to TEXT
        )
```

## UPDATE

For Month wise data i'll try below query like:

```
"SELECT * FROM $customerDetail WHERE $credit_date BETWEEN strftime('%d-%m-%Y', '$startDate') AND strftime('%d-%m-%Y', '$currentDate')"
/*SELECT * FROM CustomerDetail WHERE credit_date BETWEEN strftime('%d-%m-%Y', '01/02/2019') AND strftime('%d-%m-%Y', '23/02/2019')*/
```

But it's give me **`arralistSize = 0`**.

**After that i can write new query like:**

```
"SELECT * FROM $customerDetail WHERE $credit_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$currentDate'"
/*SELECT * FROM CustomerDetail WHERE credit_date BETWEEN '01/02/2019' AND '23/02/2019'*/
```

In this query data will return. **But it's return all data without any filtering.**

If anyone knows why this work like this please help me.

**MY DATA LIST**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

## Solution :

**Solution for MONTH wise**

I just change date format **`"dd/mm/yyyy"`** TO **`"yyyy/mm/dd"`** and re insert all data.

AND Fire below QUERY :

```
"SELECT * FROM $customerDetail WHERE $credit_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$currentDate'"
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a `Date` data type like other RDBMS's. It treats dates as `TEXT`.
So when it compares the `credit_date` column it actually does compare strings. 
This would be fine if you stored your dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and compared against the same format. 
But if you store your dates in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` then you can't compare.
So the best solution would be to change the format of the column `credit_date` to `YYYY-MM-DD`.
If this is not possible then you have to transform the string value of the column like this:

```
substr(credit_date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(credit_date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(credit_date, 1, 2)
```

Now you can use this in a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM $customerDetail 
WHERE substr($credit_date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr($credit_date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr($credit_date, 1, 2)
BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$currentDate'
```

But you have to make sure that `$startDate` and `$currentDate` are also in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: So, is your problem solved? If so, mention it in your question.

Comment: month wise filtering is solve. but as i mention in my question left 2nd and 3rd points is remaining.